# Apply visual theme to highMaps?

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I want to apply visual theme Dark Unica https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon/dark-unica in the jsfiddle mentioned in the link , i also tried to change the background color, how should i do it and is this  lat/log map ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a HighCharts theme, just load it's .js file.  For dark-unica:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/themes/dark-unica.js"></script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ne1w0h4m/

And, yes.  That is a HighCharts lat/lon map chart.